# Transitioning from CentOS 7.9 to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, centos

I have a server with CentOS 7.9 and over many years (5+) this server has a lot of bespoke tweaks and customisations to various programs and settings on it, although **not** to the OS itself.

I have read [this similar topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15471/ubuntu-vs-centos-and-binary-compatibility) but it is many years old, although it resassures me in part, I am looking to know:

**If I transfer a server contents en-mass from CentOS 7.9 to Ubuntu 20.04 will Ubuntu [probably] run everything that was on my CentOS or are there some expected tripfalls that I should watch out for and workaround?**

I really want to avoid having to manually set up and re-customise each and every part of the current server for the new OS, so I'm hoping there's enough flexibility/accommodation here.

If there is another OS that could work better in this regard (and is still decent as a server OS) please let me know.

Comment: having no idea what software and customizations u had done under centos 7.9, I don't know how anyone can answer such a question.   Rather than Ubuntu why not stick with CentOS-9.x ?  I would think that would have the best chance of compatibility to your centos-7.9 setup.

Comment: my experience generally its a GLIBC issue and its when trying to run something compiled under RHEL/CentOS 8.x under 7.x.  Usually stuff compiled under centos 8.x or higher with later versions of GLIBC will work on RHEL/CENTOS 7.x having earlier versions of glibc.  Again just one of many things that can cause a problem.

Comment: @ron to clarify, the settings and hardcode are changes to programs on the machine and not the OS itself. What I'm asking is about if I can easily simply wrap up and export all the non-OS stuff from my CentOS to the Ubuntu OS with minimum bumps; or if there are expected issues, as you mention, the GLIBC thing is something I was not aware of and will have to read up on. Thanks.

Comment: @ron while unfamiliar with CentOS 9 I think you're refering to CentOS Stream? Which I've read quite a few (some very) negative reports about and would prefer not to use this.

Comment: as an end user the *Stream* aspect makes no difference to me, its just version 9 running on kernel 5.x; I think they've overblown the *stream* part.  If you are unfamiliar with it then I wouldn't judge it until you try it out.  You can find negatives about anything today, negative or positive reviews mean very little without solid context behind them.

Comment: @ron I was reading issues that CentOS 9 would be in a "constant beta" mode which sounds extremely questionable for a production server. Anywho, that's by-the-by. MY query was if I can transfer things from CentOS 7 to Ubunutu quickly and easily but I guess probably not....

Comment: you say can i transfer things quickly... sure, use a 32gb usb3 stick or larger to *transfer* what you need, should take a couple minutes.  Whether the stuff you use under v7.9 works under v9 only you really could possible know at this point, since no one else can possible know here since you did not elaborate on it, which is what I said in my first comment  :dunnowhatelsetotellyouemoji:

Comment: https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/linux/what-is-centos-stream   that is not *constant beta mode*... it `**allows** you to participate in the development of future versions of Red Hat Enterprise Linux`.If anything "Fedora" would be *constant beta mode*, not CentOS